# Adding specific file to Windows Path

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I am trying to add just specific files to my PATH variable. This is because if I add the whole folder, often there are conflicting names with other folders, which is something I want to avoid. What can I do?

Comment: `PATH` is for directories only. One option would be to add a directory to `PATH` that contains shell links (.LNK files) to executable files in multiple target directories.

Comment: To run shell links from the command line without having to include the ".LNK" extension, add ".LNK" to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Also, leave the link's "start in" field empty in order to inherit the shell's working directory.

Comment: @Eryk Thanks, this is already what I was looking for